# CSS and Javascript not applied when using Orbeon Embedding API

Tags: orbeon

I have set up a Tomcat instance based on the `orbeon-embedding.war` managed to call forms from another Orbeon instance via nav-tabs links.

However, whilst the forms are loaded correctly in the `<div>`, no styles have been applied and none of the javascript functionality works.

In the host instance, the `.css` and `.js` files are specified in `properties.local`.
In the client instance, I have added filters for `.css`, `.js` and `.png` to the web.xml which resolved 404 errors. When viewing the page source, the links to these resources work.  The only remaining 404s I get are the state updates for `xforms-server`.

I have used the default `index.jsp` in `orbeon-embedding.war` as a basis for my launch page.

Is there something that I am  missing here?

Does jQuery need to be added to the client page?

Comment: Ok, I think I have resolved the .css issue - the selectors were body.orbeon so I replaced with .orbeon to allow them to work when the form is embedded inside a <div class="container">

Comment: You're saying that you had to add the `orbeon` class to the container in your own HTML? This shouldn't be necessary. What version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: Yes, the css file is used then the form is loaded in the usual way via the formrunner.

Comment: And what version of Orbeon Forms were you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Orbeon 2016.2

Comment: Got it; last time I tried, this wasn't necessary anymore with 2016.3. Anyhow, I'm glad you found the solution to this one!